# Is MSVC's implementation of the STL overriding the warning level to 3?

Tags: c++, stl, warnings, msvc12

In a project where my warning level is set to 4, some warnings are not detected when using the STL as implemented by MSVC12. Here's a concrete example:

```
#pragma warning(default:4365)
int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    int fillVal = -1;
    std::vector<unsigned int> v( 5 );
    std::fill( v.begin(), v.end(), fillVal );   // (underflow) no warning
    std::fill<std::vector<unsigned int>::iterator, unsigned int>( v.begin(), v.end(), fillVal );    // (underflow) warning C4365
        return 0;
}
```

It looks like at the top of xutility where `std::fill` is, there is this code:

```
#pragma warning(push,3)
// contents...
#pragma warning(pop)
```

But how come I don't detect this warning 4365 (of level 4) when compiling my code?
Is there an easy way to get the warning for the underflow in the example above?

Edit:typo

Comment: *"how come I don't detect this warning 4365 (of level 4)"*, As you noticed, warning level has changed in xutility header, and warning would be there.